# App doesn't read {{ on views

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a form to delete a row in my db:

```
 @foreach ($CostStatuses as $CostStatus)
   <tr> 
     <td class="table-text">
       <div>
         <a href="/costStatus/{{ $CostStatus->id }}/edit">
           {{ $CostStatus->status_name }}
         </a>
       </div>   
     </td>
     <td> 
       {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'CostStatus/' . $CostStatus->id, 'class' => 'pull-right')) }}
       {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
       {{ Form::submit('Delete this Nerd', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) }}
       {{ Form::close() }}  
     </td>  
   </tr> 
 @endforeach
```

But the html shows the form inside the `{{ }}` as a text to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `{{}}` does not execute the contents inside. Use `{!! !!}`.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade  Go to that url and see this section Displaying Unescaped Data.

Answer (score 0):

LAready fixed:

Just change `{{` for `{!!`.